# Change product name throws error: llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

After I tried to change the product name of my app, I get this error when I build or debug.

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Thats the only info I get. In other posts I have seen here, they often have some other error thats lead up to this. Does anyone have any idea what happened here? Or better – how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try deleting the app from the phone, clean, and if it doesn't work also restart xcode.